# Is this a valid method to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n i = (n^2+n)/2$?

Tags: proof-verification, summation

> **Teacher:** Thou shalt show the following $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

**Student:** Assume there's a polynomial $p(i)$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}.$$ [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431042/how-do-you-calculate-a-sum-over-a-polynomial/) $$p(n)=q(n)−q(n−1)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}-\frac{(n-1)^2+(n-1)}{2}=n$$
Hence $p(i)=i$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

> **The Question** Is this approach valid? (or is it circular)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1431042/5531)

Comment: It is a good approach (induction) written in a *very bad* way.

Comment: That would also show that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + C$ for any constant $C$...

Comment: No, your argument asserts there is such a $p$, without any argument why. I'm asking why there isn't a $p$ for $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$, for example. You have to tell us why there must be a $p$. With care, you can make your argument an argument by induction - you've already shown the case $n=1$, then use the logic you've given to show if true for $n$ then true for $n+1$. But as it stands now, it is wrong.

Comment: Related: Let $f(i)=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$. Then $f(i)-f(i-1)=i$ and therefore $1+2+3+\cdots+n=f(1)-f(0)+f(2)-f(1)+\cdots +f(n)-f(n-1)=f(n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have shown the following:

> If there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^np(i) = \frac{n^2+n}2$$
>   then that polynomial is equal to $p(i) = i$.

You did **not** prove that the polynomial $p$ exists. Therefore, you did not prove the statement. Sorry, logic dictates:

In order to prove the statement $q$, you need to prove $p\implies q$ **and** you need to prove $p$.

In your case, you still need to prove that there exists some polynomial that the sum is true, and the easiest way to do that is to prove your original statement.

Comment: @Trollolo **Professor**: "really? It's obvious? Well, if it's obvious, then you should be able to prove it in one or two lines."

Comment: @Trollolo Also, your "trolling" does not make you look funny. It makes you look $12$ years old.

Comment: @Trollolo Obvious? Not at all. Is there a $p$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p(i) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1$? Because, per your argument, if there is such a $p$, then $p(i)=i$, again.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Very nice example. I think you should actually write a full answer to explain this logic.

Comment: @5xum **Student**: "being obvious isn't synonymous with being easily provable."

Comment: @Trollolo **Professor**: That's academic. I don't care what your definition of obvious is. You cannot say "this is obvious" and get a free pass. Obvious or not, I want you to prove your point.

Comment: @Trollolo My calculus professor had a reply to any student who dared use the word obvious. He always said "my dear colleague, 'obvious' is my word. You are yet to prove worthy of using it."